# IP Address of Google App engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed an application in Google App engine.

I'm able to get the IP address of the machine where this app deployed but my question is does this app always runs on same IP or any chance of running on different IP.

Because google app engine is a cloud solution , it runs multiple instances at a time in multiple places.

Thanks

Comment: different IP, over time

Comment: For details read this : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip

Comment: absolutely no guarantees what IP address.  Remember no client communicates directly with you application. Everything is mediated by googles infrastructure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GAE uses different IPs. If you'd like more info I found this link:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip

Comment: This link is outdated / broken

Comment: As of December 2023, you can find the possible IP addresses ranges from JSON endpoint described in this documentation: Outbound IP addresses for App Engine services  |  App Engine standard environment for Python 2  |  Google Cloud - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses

Answer (score 9):

**(Jun 2021)**: The previous/existing answers no longer reflect today's current practices (and in fact, that documentation page has been removed). As a cloud service, the IP blocks are ephemeral and rotate.

Similar to the script posted by [@speedplane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234270/speedplane) is the one on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/outbound-ip-addresses#outbound-ip-addresses) so you can see what the possible address blocks are for traffic coming from App Engine (outbound IP addresses). However, if your purpose is to use App Engine with static IP addresses, you have two different options based on whether it's inbound or outbound.

The current recommendation (as of 2020) for **inbound static IP** users is to create a load balancer with a static IP that redirects to your App Engine (and other) apps. See these resources for more information:

1. The [load balancer and CDN announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/better-load-balancing-for-app-engine-cloud-run-and-functions) (Jul 2020)
2. [Cloud Load Balancing product documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/)

For **outbound static IP** addresses, you would create a VPC network, associate a static IP with it, and route all your App Engine traffic through the VPC and out to the Internet via a Cloud NAT gateway and your specified static IP address. See these resources for more information:

1. [Outbound IP addresses page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/outbound-ip-addresses) in the App Engine docs
2. [Serverless VPC access page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access)
3. [Cloud NAT product pages](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs)

**(Jan 2022 update)**: I refactored that script above (to get the current rotating IP blocks) to clean it up a bit and to make it Python 2-3 compatible and got the Google networking tools team to publish it in an [open source repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/networking-tools-python/tree/main/tools/cidr) for any community-contributed updates. The "dump Google CIDR blocks" script linked to at the top now imports the script from that repo directly.

Answer (score 1):

Google [does have documentation on how to do this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip), but there are quite a few commands you need to run just to get the up-to-date IP address range. Rather than do that every time, I've written a small python script that will perform those actions and pull up-to-date IP address ranges.

To run run the code below, just call `print(list(get_all_ip_cidrs()))`:

```
import re
import logging
import subprocess

def get_netblock_ips_cidr(netblock_id):
    '''Run the nslookup comamnd on the given netlock, and yield all of the ip
     address cidr addresses'''
    netblock = "_cloud-netblocks%d.googleusercontent.com"%netblock_id
    logging.info("Running Netblock %s", netblock)
    CMD = 'nslookup -q=TXT %s 8.8.8.8'%netblock
    p = subprocess.Popen(CMD, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    re_ips = re.compile(r"ip4:(?P<ipcidr>[\.\d]+/\d+)")
    num = 0
    for m in re_ips.finditer(out):
        yield m.group('ipcidr')
        num += 1
    logging.info("Netblock %s: Found %d IPs", netblock, num)

def get_all_ip_cidrs(max_net_block_ranges = 10):
    '''Run it across '''
    netblock_id = 0
    for netblock_id in range(1, max_net_block_ranges):
        for cidr in get_netblock_ips_cidr(netblock_id):
            yield cidr
    logging.info("Finished after %d netblocks"%netblock_id)
```